# XSLT-1.0 How to pick multiple tags between two similar tags as it is?

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using xsl to transform xml to xml. Could you please help me to write xsl code to convert input to output? I need the data as rich text data in CDATA for first two tags. Thanks in advance.

Input:

```
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
    <THE-VALUE>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498885">Main Description</h1>
            <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
            <p>**<img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166?accept=none&amp;private"/>**</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498886">Key Consideration</h1>
            <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498887">Skills</h1>
            <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498888">Synonyms</h1>
            <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </THE-VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
```

Output:

```
<MainDescription>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>**<img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg"/>**</p>
    ]]>
</MainDescription>
<KeyConsiderations>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
    ]]>
</KeyConsiderations>
<Skills>
    <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
</Skills>
<Synonyms>
    <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
</Synonyms>
```

I am able to get elements from h1 using below code. But I don't have clue for getting values of '< p >' so I marked it as ?????????. Please help to get solution for ?????????.

```
<xsl:for-each select="my:THE-VALUE/xhtml:div/xhtml:h1">
    <xsl:variable name="ReqIFTextTags" select="translate(., ' ', '')"></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$ReqIFTextTags}">
        <xsl:value-of select="?????????"></xsl:value-of>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: So are the children of  `MainDescription` and `KeyConsiderations` in the wanted output put in a CDATA section and those of `Skills` and `Synonyms` not? And if you use XSLT 1, which processor exactly is that? Trying to convert elements like those `<p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>` into markup in a CDATA section is difficult in pure XSLT 1 unless you can make use of extensions or import a library like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrapping the siblings following the `h1` elements into a wrapper element created from the `h1` element in XSLT 1 is possible with a key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="h1-group" match="xhtml:div/*[not(self::xhtml:h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:h1[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div[xhtml:h1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:h1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h1">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:p">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy.

Serializing the contents of those elements to markup is best done with an extension function (if your used XSLT 1 processor has one or easily allows setting it up) or with a library for that task like http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl, then you can serialize the elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
    cdata-section-elements="MainDescription KeyConsideration"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="h1-group" match="xhtml:div/*[not(self::xhtml:h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:h1[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div[xhtml:h1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:h1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h1">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())" mode="xml-to-string"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>


</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Having a CDATA section requires to know the elements in advance and name then in advance e.g. `<xsl:output cdata-section-elements="MainDescription KeyConsideration"/>`, as I have done in above sample, also online at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/1.

As you have the original elements in the XHTML namespace but your desired output has the serialized `p` elements in no namespace, you would first need to push the elements through a template that strips the namespace and then push them through the mode `xml-to-string`, this additionally requires the use of an extension function like `exsl:node-set`:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xhtml exsl"
    version="1.0">

  <xsl:import href="http://lenzconsulting.com/xml-to-string/xml-to-string.xsl"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"
    cdata-section-elements="MainDescription KeyConsideration"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:key name="h1-group" match="xhtml:div/*[not(self::xhtml:h1)]" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::xhtml:h1[1])"/>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:div[xhtml:h1]">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="xhtml:h1"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:h1">
      <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
          <xsl:variable name="rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
          </xsl:variable>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="exsl:node-set($rtf-with-xhtml-ns-stripped)/node()" mode="xml-to-string"/>
      </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="xhtml:p">
      <p>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </p>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtqy/2

Comment: This looks perfect except result includes below two tags. How to remove below tags from result?
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
  <THE-VALUE>

Comment: Well, I have posted different suggestions and samples, you will need to tell me at least which one of the three does the "perfect" job. The elements are copied from the input by the identity template (the one with `match="@* | node()"`), so depending on your other needs you can remove it or your can bypass it from the root with e.g. `<xsl:template match="/"><xsl:apply-templates select="//xhtml:div"/></xsl:template>`, which would only process any XHTML `div` descendants.

Comment: The third one is the perfect solution I am looking for. Hats of to you! Thank you. The code works fine individually. But I am facing difficulty when I integrate this with existing xsl code. Could you please tell how to use this xsl with existing xsl?

Comment: I figured it out. The solution works like charm. Thanks a lot @Martin Honnen for your help.