# XSLT-1.0 How to edit tag elements data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am using xsl to transform xml to xml. Could you please help me to write xsl code to convert input to output? I need the data as rich text data in CDATA for first two tags. Thanks in advance.

Note: I have the solution from Martin @ [XSLT-1.0 How to pick multiple tags between two similar tags as it is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220631/) but now I need to edit  value. How to do that? Please help.

Input:

```
<ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
    <THE-VALUE>
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498885">Main Description</h1>
            <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
            <p>**<img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166?accept=none&amp;private"/>**</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498886">Key Consideration</h1>
            <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498887">Skills</h1>
            <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
            <h1 dir="ltr" id="_1536217498888">Synonyms</h1>
            <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
        </div>
    </THE-VALUE>
</ATTRIBUTE-VALUE>
```

Output:

```
<MainDescription>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The main description text goes here.</p>
        <p>**<img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg"/>**</p>
    ]]>
</MainDescription>
<KeyConsiderations>
    <![CDATA[
        <p>Line1 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
        <p>Line2 The key consideration text goes here.</p>
    ]]>
</KeyConsiderations>
<Skills>
    <p>Line1 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line2 The Skills text goes here.</p>
    <p>Line3 The Skills text goes here.</p>
</Skills>
<Synonyms>
    <p>The Synonyms text goes here.</p>
</Synonyms>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the first two tags as CData, just add this template to your XSLT

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:h1[position() > 2]">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Or, if by "first two tags" you mean just "MainDescription" and "KeyConsideration", try this template instead....

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:h1[. != 'Main Description' and . != 'Key Consideration']">
  <xsl:element name="{translate(., ' ', '')}">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('h1-group', generate-id())"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

EDIT: If you want to "edit" one of the child nodes too, then simply add a template for the element, or attribute, you wish to modify. For each, to modify the `src` attribute of `img` do this

```
<xsl:template match="xhtml:p/xhtml:img/@src">
  <xsl:attribute name="src">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before(., '?'), '.jpg')" />
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

Note, this is just an example, as you did not make clear exactly what logic you required for modifying the value, so I have assumed you just want to replace the query string portion with a file extension of ".jpg".

Comment: Apology if the question is confusing. Your answer is correct but I already have that answer from Martin. I want to edit the <img> tag data to get the result like below.

Input: 
 <p><img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166?accept=none&amp;private"/></p>

Output: 
<p>**<img alt="Embedded Image" class="embeddedImageLink" id="_1536739954166" src="_9c3778a0-d596-4eef-85fa-052a5e1b2166.jpg"/>**</p>

Comment: @VishalSharnagat - I have expanded my answer to show how you could achieve this.